# Content Search Webpart is not displaying after adding ddl.ClearSelection()

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I'm having issue on asp:dropdownlist and search result display. One of the issues is "Cannot have multiple values on DropDownList", so, I looked it up and most of the suggestion were the use of ClearSelection method.

I added it and the error message was gone, however, the next issue is the search result was not displaying.

When I debugged the code, it was able to pull up the data and it was bounded to the datasource. I have also added try-catch to see if there any exception, however it passed the try block successfully.

Here is the code snippet for ddl.ClearSelection

```
try
{
    this.ddlSearchBy.ClearSelection();
    this.ddlSearchBy.Items.FindByValue(csrSearchFormFilter.SearchBy).Selected = true;
}
catch (Exception e)
{

}
```

Then, here is code snippet for data binding and display:

```
public void Configure()
{
    if (this.DataSource != null && this.DataSource.Count == 1)
    {
        //do code here
    }

    this.webpartSearchResults.DataSource = this.DataSource;
    this.webpartSearchResults.DataBind();
}
```

Is the ClearSelection method can affect other webparts? If so, is there a way to eliminate the error on DropDownList without affecting the search result?

Any insight is much appreciated. 
Thanks for your time.

UPDATE:

The dropdown is there to filter the fields that will be shown in the form.
It is working in this pattern:

Case 1:

- DDL: item 1
- Field: box 1, box2, box 3
- Action: click search button
- Result: it displays the matched keys
- DDL: item 2
- Field: box2, box 3
- Action: click search button
- Result: it displays the matched keys

However, in this pattern:

Case 1:

- DDL: item 2
- Field: box 1, box2, box 3
- Action: click search button
- Result: it displays the matched keys
- DDL: item 1
- Field: box2, box 3
- Action: click search button
- Result: it no longer displays the matched keys - this happens when i selected the last item in the dropdownlist, then select another value after i click the search button.

Comment: "I have also added try-catch to see if there any exception". Actually this will prevent you from seeing any exceptions, because you catch them and then ignore them, and there is nowhere to put a breakpoint inside your empty catch. If you remove the try/catch then the application will halt if there is a problem. If you're in debug mode it'll break and you can inspect the details. Suppressing exceptions like this is a well-known anti-pattern.

Comment: The error sounds like it is because you're setting multiple items to be selected...sounds like a logic problem in your code more than anything. Anyway the code as shown does not explain the relationship between the dropdown and the webpart, it's not clear when these two snippets of code get executed during the page lifecycle, where the dropdownlist is situated in relation to the webpart, or even if they're in the same page (I guess they are, but it's not actually clear). So it's hard to say what effect they would have on each other. Does the dropdown influence the data source somehow?

Comment: Thank you @ADyson. I'll keep this in mind. I made an update to answer your 2nd comment. :)

Comment: That's more helpful but we still need to understand the relationships of the actual code. It's still not obvious what happens when you click search, and how the search results are derived, and how any of the code you've provided is related to that. We know _nothing_ about your application don't forget, except what you tell us. In order to fix anything, we first need enough code and information to reproduce the problem (or at least be able to see how to).